# How to pass a javascript variable into PHP variable for loop execution on basis of selected images

Tags: wordpress

I have selected images count in JavaScript but I need this to pass into PHP variable for loop execution on basis of selected images.

Comment: javascript a client side language and php is a server side language . you can use AJAX to pass the variable data from javascript to php.

Comment: you able to store the data in text box and get it in php.

Comment: i tried alot but data is visible but not execute loop